# Proving linear independence of a variable set

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I was given this problem:

Show that for a set {$v, w, z$} of vectors of a vector space $V$ , the set {$v, w, z$} is linearly independent, if and only if the set {$v, w + v, z + w + v$} is linearly independent.

I had to do another problem that involved proving linear independence and I did it by showing that $x_1v_1 +. . .+x_kv_k = 0$  only had one solution $x_1 = . . . = x_k = 0$ but when doing that I had integers to work with. I don't really know how to do that with these variables.

Comment: You can start with assuming that $\{v,w,z\}$ is linearly independent. Then, let $a,b,c$ be numbers such that $av + b(w+v) + c(z+w+v) = 0$. Now, sort for $v,w,z$ and show by solving a linear system that $a = b = c = 0$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp okay so when doing that, how do I "sort for $v,w,z$"? I distributed $a,b,c$ so $av+bv+bw+cv+cw+cz=0$ and then I can take that and make it $v(a+b+c) + w(b+c) + cz=0$ but I don't know how that helps. Can I say that because $v,w,z$ is linearly independent, $(a+b+c)=(b+c)=c=0$?

Comment: Exactly. And that's a linear system of equations which can be easily solved for $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix with column vectors the new system of vectors is 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1\\1&1&1\\0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and it has rank $3$. Hence it is invertible and the two systems of vectors have the same rank. If one of them is a basis, the other system is too.

Comment: Why does the first column have a 1 as the middle element? Why isn't it in the third position? Could you explain how you got that matrix please?